# Data type for database primary key

Tags: database, oracle, database-design, primary-key

I am creating a  database and in the tables the primary key value is 1 2 3 4 etc. My teacher said i can use number(4) for the primary key data type.

However some suggest that I use 'int(20) unsigned'

I am quite confused, what should i use...

Database is Oracle

Comment: what kind of database are you using MySQL, SQLServer ?

Comment: it depends on the size of ur data..

Comment: Hiya, read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337503/whats-the-best-practice-for-primary-keys-in-tables and then think and decide - why not declaring your id column as identity or why would you go for number and how many records your table will store etc... hope this helps, cheers!

Comment: If you are using MySQL - which seems to be indicated by the `int(20)` example, then note that the `(20)` does **not** define a length restriction. `number(4)` however - which indicates an Oracle database - *does* impose an upper limit of 9999 which seems rather small for a primary key column

Comment: Thanks horse, i then shall use number as data type with no restriction. is this recommendable'? how about numeric???

Comment: @JoseDavidGarciaLlanos: Use `NUMBER` without any restrictions (I think that is going to be translated to `NUMBER(22)` anyway)

Comment: Oracle does not have an INT type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no single right or wrong type for key attributes. Choose a data type that accurately represents the business domain and fulfils the requirements of whoever or whatever needs to use the key.