# What are the characters that count as the same character under collation of UTF8 Unicode? And what VB.net function can be used to merge them?

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0, utf-8, collation, unicode-normalization

Also what's the vb.net function that will map all those different characters into their most standard form.

For example, tolower would map A and a to the same character right?

I need the same function for these characters

german

ß  ===  s
Ü ===  u
Χιοσ == Χίος

Otherwise, sometimes I insert Χιοσ and latter when I insert Χίος mysql complaints that the ID already exist.

So I want to create a unique ID that maps all those strange characters into a more stable one.

Comment: Neither UTF8 nor Unicode are collations.  Please be more precise.

Comment: My collation in mysql is UTF8_unicode_ci

Comment: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-unicode-sets.html

Comment: Also take a look at this [link](http://www.collation-charts.org/mysql60/)

Comment: so I am dealing with "1.2 Canonical Equivalence" where are the list of those Canonical equivalence and is there a vb.net function that map all canonical equivalence glyphs into it's most standard form?

Comment: Can anyone turn this into an answer so I can give you easy points.

Comment: Same question as [Is there a function in vb.net that will tell us whether 2 string is equivalent under UTF8 unicode collation?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10713304/is-there-a-function-in-vb-net-that-will-tell-us-whether-2-string-is-equivalent-u

Comment: I forget. Similar but not the same. Either case it's not answered

Comment: Maybe that  _MySQL complaints that the ID already exist_  because IDs are not case sensitive? For Greek letters Sigma: `'σς'.ToUpper()` gives `ΣΣ`…

Answer (score 1):

For the encoding aspect of the thing, look at [`String.Normalize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.normalize.aspx).  Notice also its overload that specifies a particular [normal form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.normalizationform.aspx) to which you want to convert the string, but the default normal form (C) will work just fine for nearly everyone who wants to "*map all those different characters into their most standard form*".

However, things get more complicated once you move into the database and deal with collations.

Unicode normalization does not ever change the character case.  It covers only cases where the characters are basically equivalent - look the same<sup>1</sup>, mean the same thing.  For example,

```
 Χιοσ != Χίος,
```

The two sigma characters are considered [non-equivalent](http://unicode.org/faq/greek.html), and the accented iota (`\u1F30`) is equivalent to a sequence of two characters, the plain iota (`\u03B9`) and the accent (`\u0313`).

Your real problem seems to be that you are using Unicode strings as primary keys, which is [not the most popular database design practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/337503/1235565).  Such primary keys take up more space than needed and are bound to change over time (even if the initial version of the application does not plan to support that).  Oh, and I forgot their sensitivity to collations.  Instead of identifying records by Unicode strings, have the database schema [generate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/example-auto-increment.html) meaningless sequential integers for you as you insert the records, and demote the Unicode strings to mere attributes of the records.  This way they can be the same or different as you please.

It may still be useful to normalize them before storing for the purpose of searching and safer subsequent processing; but the particular case insensitive *collation* that you use will no longer restrict you in any way.

---

<sup>1</sup>Almost the same in case of compatibility normalization as opposed to canonical normalization.

Comment: String.Normalize won't turn a ß into an s. It... "Returns a new string whose textual value is the same as this string, but whose binary representation" I want to change the textual value so it match the standard one.

Comment: @JimThio - That is because ß and s are simply different letters.  They have nothing in common except when sorting.  Your app should not have unique constraints on columns where you cannot meet them.

Comment: They are different letters but utf8 collation says they're the same and doesn't allow ids that differ only on those 2.

Comment: @JimThio - You mean ss, not s.  Collation specifies ordering rules, not equivalence rules.  Just don't use such strings as ids; or use the binary collation if you must.

Comment: I like to use such strings as IDs. It make it easier for me to debug. Ah ha, the id is mc-donald--6.19-107.7 it must be that mcDonald restaurant.