# Which Unicode characters are "composing" characters (whose sole purpose is to add accent, tilda)?

Tags: vb.net, unicode

This is related to

[What are the characters that count as the same character under collation of UTF8 Unicode? And what VB.net function can be used to merge them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834300/what-are-the-characters-that-count-as-the-same-character-under-collation-of-utf8)

This is how I plan to do this:

Use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374126%28v=vs.85%29.aspx to turn the string into

KD form.

Basically it'll turn most variation such as superscript into the normal number. Also it decompose tilda and accent into 2 characters.

Next step would be to remove all characters whose sole purpose is tildaing or accenting character.

How do I know which characters are like that? Which characters are just "composing characters"

How do I find such characters? After I find those, how do I get rid of it? Should I scan character by character and remove all such "combining characters?"

For example:
Character from 300 to 362 can be gotten rid off.

Then what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combining characters are listed in [UnicodeData.txt](ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt) as having a nonzero Canonical_Combining_Class, and a General_Category of `Mn` (Mark, nonspacing).

Comment: how do we know that in vb.net?

Answer (score 2):

For each character in the string, call [GetUnicodeCategory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a91e3zb6.aspx) and check the [UnicodeCategory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.unicodecategory.aspx) for NonSpacingMark, SpacingCombiningMark or EnclosingMark.

You may be able to do it more efficiently using regex, eg `Regex.Replace(str, "\p{M}", "")`.