# Cakephp Composite Primary Key

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.5

I am new in Cakephp. Please, how can I implement this logic in cakephp model knowing that cake doesn't accept composite key.

I have 3 Tables.

```sql
CREATE TABLE satelites(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT,
    location TEXT);

CREATE TABLE sensors (
    satelite_id INTEGER, 
    type VARCHAR(100),
    unitofmeasurement TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY(satelite_id,type),
    CONSTRAINT satelite_id FOREIGN KEY(satelite_id) 
        REFERENCES satelites(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE sensordatas(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    satelite_id INTEGER, 
    sensortype VARCHAR(100), 
    value REAL,
    valuetext INTEGER, 
    timestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(satelite_id,sensortype) 
       REFERENCES sensors(satelite_id,type)
);
```

- satelites has many sensors
- sensors belongs to satelites
- sensors has many sensorsdatas
- sensordatas belongs to sensors

Comment: sensordatas belongs to sensors : with which field ? type ?

Comment: sensordatas linked with sensors through 2 foreign key : satelite_id and sensortype. ==> FOREIGN KEY(satelite_id,sensortype) 
       REFERENCES sensors(satelite_id,type)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you, you had to rework your table schema for use all CakePHP power.

**It s a good pratice to have an 1 primary key by table** (for cakephp but for all tables in general)

So 
sensors must have id

and sensordatas : sensor_id

and after simple sensordata belongsTo sensorId.

Comment: you will win a lot of time with this structure, and use a good pratices. see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337503/whats-the-best-practice-for-primary-keys-in-tables

Answer (score 0):

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/quickstart.html#creating-the-database

CakePHP 3 now supports composite keys for whatever purposes as these dont help with record access. So as suggested, We must include the **id** primary key to all our tables for selection and **updating.**