# entity framework and tables requiring primary keys

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am looking at entity framework and trying learn more about it. So have created a simple project to play with.

I found out that I can't add a table if it does not have a primary key. Reading some posts on here and other places I think that is correct. It is apparently to allow EF to do deletions and updates etc. If I have a project where there will be no deletions or updates, just select queries I'm guessing it doesn't matter what column I make as a primary key? I understand most tables should have a primary this is just a question out of curiosity.

Also can EF handle a primary key on multiple columns, I assume so?

Comment: Also for reading, EF requires unique primary keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you application does not require deletions or updates, son or later you will need a primary key. If you set a good primary key ([here you have a good guide for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337503/whats-the-best-practice-for-primary-keys-in-tables)), the task of programming will be much easier. And yes, EF can handle primary key on multiple columns.