# Lookup tables - should I use an id column or just use the value?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I have many lookup tables that look like:

```
id(pk) type(unique)
---
1 UNIVERSITY OF ARIZONA
2 UNIVERSITY OF MIAMI
3 TOKYO UNIVERSITY
```

Let's say `type` is a unique string in all cases.

I am questioning whether I should use the `id(pk)` or just do:

```
type(pk)
----
UNIVERSITY OF ARIZONA
...
```

Comment: Related: [What's the best practice for primary keys in tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/337503/190597)

Comment: This is an easily googled obvious faq that should not be asked or answered again. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the primary key.  Here are some reasons:

- Integers are generally more efficient than strings for joins.
- Integers are definitely more efficient from a storage perspective -- the strings are longer than the numbers.
- You might want to change the name one day, say, `'UNIVERSITY OF ARIZONA (TUCSON)'`.
- Primary keys are really what is expected for the foreign key relationship.

Comment: What about the case of filters (`WHERE/WHERE IN`)? Do integer columns provide more efficient lookups? I'm assuming yes due to the more efficient indexes/storage. So if I was building some sort of filter UI, the UI should pass to the server: `[{ id: 1, type: 'UNIVERSITY OF ARIZONA' }]` ( or simply `[1]`), then on the server I should map to the ids: `[1]`, then do a `WHERE IN [1]`?

Comment: Also, integers don't have to deal with lowercase vs. uppercase, spelling differences, leading and/or trailing whitespace, and more ....

Comment: Ok, I'm thinking since the primary key is on the integer `id`, I should be filtering on that column anyway since an efficient index is created on it by default, whereas `type` doesn't have an index.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Can you take a look at this? https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/232952/joining-40-normalized-tables-for-200-columns-to-display-detailed-user-profile I wanted to get your opinion because you help out with all of my SQL queries. :) I'm finding that integer surrogate keys require so many extra joins that the benefits don't seem worth it compared to the performance penalty.