# New with databases, having problems wiith primary key

Tags: mysql, database, primary-key

I have a table where events organized by a sports center are stored.
I created it like this:

```
create table events(
  name varchar(20) primary key,
  description varchar(150),
  type varchar(20) not null,
  event_date not null,
  event_start time not null,
  event_end time not null,
  room_name varchar(20) not null,
  foreign key(room_name) references rooms(name) on update cascade on delete cascade);
```

now I have realized that events with the same name can exist as long as they are not on the same day.
For example, a swimming competition can be held several times in a month and still have the same name. How can I modify the table so that the primary key is made up of name and date without having to delete and re-create the table?

Comment: Why not have an auto-increment integer primary key and leave the data for the data columns?

Comment: add a unique attribute to the competition name. And imho you should have an autoincrement id as primary key, not the competition name

Comment: @KenzoBetter Is there a reason why you want to go for composite primary keys consisting of name and dates? Why not have two separate tables event_name(id, name, description, type) and events(event_name_id, event_date, event_start, event_end, room_name) ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `alter table` statement to drop the primary key and add a new one:

```sql
ALTER TABLE events DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE events ADD PRIMARY KEY (name, event_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's worth [reading up about primary keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337503/whats-the-best-practice-for-primary-keys-in-tables?rq=1).

As @mureinik says, you can drop the original key and create a new key - but your design has a few problems.

Firstly, primary keys should never change. Columns like "Name" suggest they can change - even if the user corrects a typo, or if the event changes its name (e.g. to add a sponsor). This goes for "room" too.

Secondly, your design combines two logical entities into a single table. I *think* you have an entity called event_type (tennis tournament), and an event instance (1 July 2021). I think there will be more attributes of event type, which you won't want to copy for each instance (e.g. "description").

So, I think your schema is more like

```
event_type
----------
event_id int pk
event_name varchar
event_type varchar
event_description varchar

event_instance
--------------
event_type_id int fk pk
event_date date pk
event_start time not null,
event_end time not null,
room_id int fk
```