# Should I use an ID?

Tags: sql

I have a table with products like

**Products**

```
id
name
styles_id
```

I also have a table with styles like

**Styles**

```
id
name
```

When I add a style to a product I use a foreign key id value from the `Styles` table. I do this for a few years now on a lot of projects but I was thinking WHY? It would be a lot easier to get the products if I have a `Styles` table with a name as primary key and without an `id`. So I do not have to do a join to get the style name of the product. I see it is done a lot but what are the advantages of the `id` in the `Styles` table?

Comment: Also a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/1229173/458741, http://stackoverflow.com/q/3747730/458741, http://stackoverflow.com/q/590442/458741, etc... this is one of the older "wars" in DB design... now you know the keywords to look for there's a lot of information out there, not just on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you the links helped alot, but what would you suggest in this situation ? I think the only disadvantage of no id is if i want to change the style name but i could easily add ON UPDATE CASCADE ..

Comment: I don't really see how your suggestion is different to the links @Sven. If you feel like you want a natural key now the general suggestion is to use a surrogate key but add a unique not null constraint on the name. That way, you can change your mind in the future without having to alter _all_ your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main advantage is that you can change the name of a product without affecting the references.

You could add multiple names, if, for instance, you wanted to internationalize your database.

Almost every time that I fail to put an auto incremented id in a table, I regret it as some point.  That might be when duplicates appear in the table and I want to delete them.  That might be when the structure changes in an unexpected way, such as internationalization.  That might be when I want to know the last thing that was entered -- auto-incremented id provides that information.  Now, I put such an id in almost every table that I create, even in databases where it is painful to do, such as most versions of Oracle.

Comment: +1 - also, using a **numerical** `id` is (a) faster on joins, and (b) not prone to misspellings and uppercase/lowercase issues and more hassle from using strings as identifiers.