# last record from database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Get the last record from a Microsoft SQL database table using ASP.net (VB) onto a web form.

Comment: you haven't tried doing it, have you?

Comment: Challenge accepted, this sounds exciting!

Comment: Please provide more details as your question is not clear.

Comment: oh how I wish I could vote to close... we really need the ability to stamp on rudimentary questions like this :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming he's trying to retrieve the last inserted record.  As Ariel pointed out, the question is rather ambiguous.

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Table ORDER BY ID DESC
```

If you have an identity column called ID, this is easiest.  If you don't have an identity PK column for example a GUID you wont be able to do this.

Comment: And what happens if ID isn't autonumeric, or if it's not numeric at least?

Comment: @Matias then you need refactoring

Comment: @ariel haha, you need to refactor a DB because you need to get latest added record? I'd prefer a timestamp instead of that.

Comment: He should have a PK identity column.  If he doesn't he should add one in probably.

Comment: Right, but, what about other kinds of PK?

Comment: Matias: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932913/when-having-an-identity-column-is-not-a-good-idea

Comment: @Matias, how are we meant to know anything when the original question is so vague?  Your criticism of my answer can equally be applied to your criticism.  We don't know.  This is one correct solution.  Who cares, OP probably wont be reading it anyway.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he is not talking about a many to many relationship table. On that case only a timestamp would work.

Comment: @Matias I'm also keenly waiting for your answer that takes all the unknowns into account!

Comment: @Tom Guillem, relax... I was kidding with @ariel. It's not criticism, I was just asking you what would happen if this isn't auto-numeric. In terms of objectivity, then, if you don't know how's his database, then why you think it has an autonumeric PK? But I repeat, don't mind it was criticism, it was just a suggestion!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic solution:

```
var order = (from i in db.orders
             where i.costumer_id.ToString() == Session["costumer_id"]
             orderby i.order_id descending
             select i).Take(1).SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more specific with actually putting it onto a web form, but the SQL to get the last record is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM    TABLE_NAME
WHERE   ID = (SELECT MAX(ID)  FROM TABLE_NAME)
```

Where ID is your ID and TABLE_NAME is your table name.