# Spring batch Custom itemWriter with insert or update mechanism

Tags: database, spring, jpa, spring-batch, upsert

I have `Spring Batch` with a basic chunk:

1. Read a CSV file.
2. Process it (Transcode some coded value into another ones).
3. Write the result into a database.

**The problem**

In some case, I want insert or update mechnism in my custom `ItemWriter`.

Exemple: I can get this 2 lines on my `CSV`

```
C006;Test;OK;01/01/1970;1
C006;Test;OK;01/01/1970;5
```

You can figure out that they are pretty similar except the last column, the strategy will be:

1. Check the database if I have a "like so" entity
2. if true, update the value with the last item that you get (in our case, the second line with the value 5 in the last column)

**What I already did?**

In my entity bean, I added a *Unique Constraint* anotation like so:

```
@Table(name = "indicator",
    uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = 
                                        { "reference", "type", "status", "date" }) })
```

I'm sure now that I cannot persist an entity with the same column's data. Then, I created a custom `ItemWriter`, and I tried to catch the *ConstraintViolationException* but it didn't work, I always get an other exeption, even when I tried the parent one.

So do you have any ideas or another way to do it?

I was think about using merge JPA functionality? what do you think about it?

**My custom ItemWriter**

```
@Component
public class ImportItemWriter implements ItemWriter<Indicator>{

    @Autowired
    protected IndicatorDao indicatorDao;

    public void write(List<? extends Indicator> items) throws Exception {

        for (Indicator item : items) {
            Indicator indicator = new Indicator();

            indicator.setReference(item.getReference());
            indicator.setType(item.getType());
            indicator.setStatus(item.getStatus());
            indicator.setDueDate(item.getDueDate());

            indicator.setValue(item.getValue());

            try {
                indicatorDao.persist(indicator);
            } catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }       
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**
***Problem Solved***
The idea of using `Composite PKey` is interesting, but I can't use it because I have to create a composite with 9 keys that's not fair in term of performance. I decided to add function to my `DAO` (`isDuplicated`) and in my custom `ItemWriter`, I just make a simple test:

```
if `isDuplicated()` then `updateEntity()` else `insertNew()`
```

Comment: Have you thought about using [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JpaItemWriter.html) directly? .. the implementation performs a entityManger.merge(..) .. if your entity have a composite pkey you could solve in this way.

Comment: Yep, I used JpaItemWriter before, but didn't work, I guess that the merge catch only with the primary key and in my case I don't care about it, I have a specific purpose, checking simultaneously 4 attributes

Comment: You could create a composite primary key with your 4 attributes :) .. but if you can't change your entity, is the same thing your "ImportItemWriter". ;) see [this link](http://uaihebert.com/tutorial-jpa-composite-primary-key/) to create composite primary key

Comment: Interesting, I'll give a try. Thanks

Comment: have you solved this issue? if yes, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 8):

One option would be to use the `ClassifierCompositeItemWriter`.  The `Classifier` would be used to determine whether to do the insert or the update.  Then you'd configure two delegates, one for inserts, one for updates.

Comment: That didn't solde the problem of catching whether i have to insert or update

Comment: What part of your needs aren't addressed with this solution?

Comment: The idea of using a Classifier is not bad at all, but in my case I have another problem. Basically, I would like to find a mechanism that allow me to identify whether I need to update or insert an item. Then, inserting or updating is not a problem, but first I need to catch the case. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

***Summarize the above comments.***

Have you thought about using [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JpaItemWriter.html) directly? .. the implementation performs a entityManger.merge(..) .. if your entity have a composite pkey you could solve in this way.

```
    <job id="writeProductsJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
        <step id="readWrite">
            <tasklet>
                <chunk reader="productItemReader" writer="productItemWriter" commit-interval="3" />
            </tasklet>
        </step>
    </job>

    <bean id="productItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaItemWriter">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
```

By an @EmbeddedId you can build a composite primary key in order to merge the entity. See this [link](http://uaihebert.com/tutorial-jpa-composite-primary-key/)

**Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CAR")
public class Car {

    @EmbeddedId
    private CarPK carPK;

    @Column
    private String name;
}
```

**Composite Primary Key**

```
@Embeddable
public class CarPK implements Serializable {

    @Column
    private String chassisSerialNumber;

    @Column
    private String engineSerialNumber;

    public CarPK(){
        // Your class must have a no-arq constructor
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(obj instanceof CarPK){
            CarPK carPk = (CarPK) obj;

            if(!carPk.getChassisSerialNumber().equals(chassisSerialNumber)){
                return false;
            }

            if(!carPk.getEngineSerialNumber().equals(engineSerialNumber)){
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return chassisSerialNumber.hashCode() + engineSerialNumber.hashCode();
    }

    //setter and getter
}
```

Comment: Great idea, I didn't knew that there was something like composite Pkey before! but before testing, conceptually speaking, is that good to create an entity that contains a composite pkey with 9 arguments?

Comment: I think that conceptually is correct if the set of each fields must be unique in your db. Is a god way also because that is handled by ORM. JPA does not have significant performance impact whether its a composite key or not. [see this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7937210/3364187)