# Hibernate -- composite keys

Tags: hibernate, database-design

My entity class `MemberDispatch` has 2 natural keys: `Members` and `Dispatch`. 
Both `Members` and `Dispatch` are entity classes themselves.

Right now, the key of `MemberDispatch` is `ID`-- a surrogate key. 
`Members` and `Dispatch` are composed in `MemberDispatch` as entity fields 
and are not part of the key.

Whenever I need to save-and-not-update, i.e., save only if a corresponding 
(`Members`, `Dispatch`) doesn't exist in `MemberDispatch`, I first am 
fetching from `MemberDispatch` (if exists) 
the record matching the (`Members`, `Dispatch`) pair, and saving 
ony if that query returns null.

If I'd instead define and use the natural keys (`Members` and `Dispatch`) 
as the key, i'd save directly without checking first a record already exists. With this, 
I'd have achieved what I'm looking for-- 
Hibernate would make sure of the uniqueness of (`Members` and `Dispatch`) pair in the database table.

I've seen [Why are composite keys discouraged in hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14112839/why-are-composite-keys-discouraged-in-hibernate) and some other 
arguments against composite keys in Hibernate.

My Q is: is there a better way of designing the entity classes without getting into composite keys?

//-------------------------

EDIT:

I achieved since by overriding `equals()` of `MemberDispatch` on fields `Members` and `Dispatch`. it's throwing a `org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException` when I attempt to save an existing (`Members`, `Dispatch`) pair.

The Q then would be - why would I need JPA uniqueness constraints (thanks JBNizet and Nathan Hughes) while I have this?

Comment: You don't need (member, dispatch) to be a composite primary key to be able to do that. All you need is a unique constraint on (member, dispatch).

Comment: @JBNizet how is it done - whats the annotation for that? so, i'd be defining a constraint for 2 fields

Comment: related: [How to introduce multi-column constraint with JPA annotations?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2772470/217324)

Comment: Yes. I don't define my schema with annotations, but with SQL. But it's possible to use an annotation to do it: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/UniqueConstraint.html

Comment: @JBNizet , NathanHughes I think I worked this around -- see my edit in the Q. how would this be any better/worse than what you suggested?

Comment: I don't see how that could work. If you haven't loaded any entity yet, and just try to insert a new entity with a member/dispatch pair that already exists in the DB, the database won't reject the insert based on your equals() method.