# 3 composite keys in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to use 3 composite keys in MySql? Is this okay?

```
create table lecturer(
  lec_id varchar(6) not null,
  lec_name varchar(18) 
  primary key(lec_id)
);

create table subject(
  sub_code varchar(6) not null,
  sub_name varchar(18) 
  primary key(sub_code)
);

create table lecDetails(
  lec_id varchar(6) not null,
  sub_code varchar(6) not null,
  sem varchar(6) not null, 
  primary key(lec_id,sub_code,sem)
  FOREIGN KEY (lec_id) REFERENCES lecturer(lec_id)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (sub_code) REFERENCES subject(sube_code)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it be ok?

Comment: Looks fine to me. As long as your need is to have a unique combination of `(lec_id, sub_code, sem)`, this should be fine and there is probably no need for a surrogate key on `lecDetails`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it depends on the structure of your table and the approximate number of records that will be stored, also the amount of hits/transactions that your table will be accessed.

For a lecture info information stored, I dont think it will cause a performance drawback, it may slow the `SELECT` command a little but not that much.

- A good question to read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460465/composite-primary-key-performance-drawback-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly **OKAY** and acceptable to use a composite primary key that includes referenced columns. It would not be acceptable if there is a `SET NULL` action or the referenced column is `NULL`.