# MySQL many-to-many optimal indices

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

I have a following MySQL code for table:

```
CREATE TABLE `tag_to_photo` (
  `tag_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `photo_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tag_id`, `photo_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

How to optimally define indices if I am going to search for both: all tags pinned to photo and all photos pinned to tag? I assume primary key can be combined. But should I define additional index for `tag_id` or `photo_id` or maybe for both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple column indexes are called `Composite Keys`, and you do not need to add separate indexes for the said columns because the `Primary Composite Key` will be enough, assuming most of your queries are similar to this:

```
SELECT  ...
    FROM tag_to_photo
    WHERE tag_id = ...
        AND photo_id = ...
```

Check the link for [Composite Keys](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) to learn more on how you can take advantage of its performance.

This [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460465/composite-primary-key-performance-drawback-in-mysql) will also provide some under the hood about composite keys, depending on your database configuration (`InnoDB`/`MyISAM`).

There could be instances that the query will get slow for `INSERT`/`UPDATE` when the table get huge. That time we can analyze the execution plan on what we can do and how to implement them to optimize your queries.

Comment: I will have the following quaries only:
SELECT tag_id FROM tag_to_photo WHERE photo_id = ...;
SELECT photo_id FROM tag_to_photo WHERE tag_id = ... OR/AND tag_id = ... AND/OR ...;

Comment: I notice that tag_id is (mostly) present in your query. Just take note that leftmost index rule of composite keys and you’ll be fine.