# text indexes vs integer indexes in mysql

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing

I have always tried to have an integer primary key on a table no matter what.  But now I am questioning if this is always necessary.

Let's say I have a product table and each product has a globally unique SKU number - that would be a string of say 8-16 characters.  Why not make this the PK?  Typically I would make this field a unique index but then have an auto incrementing int field as the PK, as I assumed it would be faster, easier to maintain, and would allow me to do things like get the last 5 records added with ease.

But in terms of optimisation, assuming I'd only ever be matching the full text field and next doing text matching queries (e.g. like %%) can you guys think of any reasons not to use a text based primary key, most likely of type varchar()?

Cheers,
imanc

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63090/surrogate-vs-natural-business-keys

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the SKU number as a primary key has some sense. You will like to index it to make searches by SKU fast. And SKU is a [natural index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_key).

However it has some penalties:

- Performance (as Coronatus said)
- Lack of design flexibility. If, for any reason, the SKU stops being globally unique you will be forced to change not only the table structure but also all your queries.
- Changing the SKU of one item will force you to change all the relationships in the database.

Answer (score -2):

Computers are MUCH faster at comparing numbers than strings.

Also, MySQL indexes of strings only contain the first 4 letters by default.

If you have strings `blabfoo, blabbar, blabboo`, the index will be totally useless because the first 4 characters are equal, so a search for "blabf" will initally match ALL 3 strings, then iterate over the results.

Basically, never use strings for indexes because they are slow and use more space.

Comment: This is simply incorrect. By default MySQL will index the entire string (unless it's a text/blob, in which case you must specify the length), and retrieving rows via an indexed string column is very fast.

Comment: @grahamparks Great comment but how fast is it compared to integer indexes?

Comment: Varchar vs INT:  The difference is mostly insignificant compared to fetching the row, parsing things, etc., _not_ numeric vs string comparison.