# Primary key varchar mysql

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table with 5 columns one of them is a uuid generate by an application. In the table the uuid colum is varchar(64) and the primary key is a int autoincremental. Is it bad idea delete the id column and use uuid like primarykey?

Comment: Do you need the `id` column? Are you inserting many rows? Do you have many secondary indexes and foreign keys? As you should guess now - The answer is: "It depends".

Comment: Are there any child tables referencing rows in that table?

Comment: Smal tables it doesn't matter at all, but with big tables millions of rows  there are some speed issues

Comment: More on speed issues with UUIDs:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid

Answer (score 0):

Probably yes! Numerical keys takes up less memory and index works with better performance at first.

I found a similar discution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578117/text-indexes-vs-integer-indexes-in-mysql)

Comment: Ok, thanks. I discard set uuid like primarykey