# Is string or int preferred for foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, ddl

I have a user table with `userid` and `username` columns, and both are unique.

Between `userid` and `username`, which would be better to use as a foreign key and why?
My Boss wants to use string, is that ok?

Comment: May I ask why you have two unique columns in the table?

Comment: Why he can not have two unique columns.Like having a ID, email and username. They can be all unique, can not they?

Comment: I admit. Silly question. Was just wondering if the two columns were actually describing the same thing. nonnb answered the question beatifully.

Comment: @Bill Thanks for editing want to improve grammer .

Comment: @Rahul: You're welcome.  I only paid attention to the title, spelling, and punctuation on the first edit.  I went through a second time and improved the grammar.

Comment: @Bill Thanks Your english is very good . want to improve mine.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

> Is string or int preferred for foreign keys?

**It depends**

There are many [existing discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63090) on the trade-offs between [Natural and Surrogate Keys](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=natural+surrogate+key) - you will need to decide on what works for you, and what the 'standard' is within your organisation.

In the OP's case, there is both a surrogate key (`int userId`) and a natural key (`char` or `varchar username`). Either column can be used as a Primary key for the table, and either way, you will still be able to enforce uniqueness of the other key.

Here are some considerations when choosing one way or the other:

**The case for using Surrogate Keys (e.g. UserId INT AUTO_INCREMENT)**

If you use a surrogate, (e.g. `UserId INT AUTO_INCREMENT`) as the Primary Key, then all tables referencing table `MyUsers` should then use `UserId` as the Foreign Key.

You can still however enforce uniqueness of the `username` column through use of an additional [unique index](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9764120/314291), e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE `MyUsers` (
  `userId` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  ... other columns
  PRIMARY KEY(`userId`),
  UNIQUE KEY UQ_UserName (`username`)
```

As per @Dagon, using a narrow primary key (like an `int`) has performance and storage benefits over using a wider (and variable length) value like `varchar`. This benefit also impacts further tables which reference `MyUsers`, as the foreign key to `userid` will be narrower (fewer bytes to fetch).

Another benefit of the surrogate integer key is that the username can be changed easily without affecting tables referencing `MyUsers`.
If the `username` was used as a natural key, and other tables are coupled to `MyUsers` via `username`, it makes it very inconvenient to change a username (since the Foreign Key relationship would otherwise be violated). If updating usernames was required on tables using `username` as the foreign key, a technique like [ON UPDATE CASCADE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6720458/314291) is needed to retain data integrity.

**The case for using Natural Keys (i.e. username)**

One downside of using Surrogate Keys is that other tables which reference `MyUsers` via a surrogate key will need to be `JOIN`ed back to the `MyUsers` table if the `Username` column is required. One of the potential benefits of Natural keys is that if a query requires only the `Username` column from a table referencing `MyUsers`, that it need not join back to `MyUsers` to retrieve the user name, which will save some I/O overhead.

Comment: +1 for a pragmatic answer, both solutions have their pro's and cons. Personally, I would prefer the Surrogate Key solution to.

Comment: Another instance in which it's occasionally preferable to use a natural key is if you find yourself constantly doing a lookup by the natural key to get the id simply to perform an update (using an ORM or something which demands the PK for its updates) or to provide it as a FK in another data set. You're doing an extra operation for limited benefit in some cases especially if the natural key is very small.

Answer (score 5):

An int is 4 bytes, a string can be as many bytes as you like. Because of that, an int will always perform better. Unless ofcourse if you stick with usernames that are less than 4 characters long :)

Besides, you should never use a column as PK/FK if the data within the column itself can change. Users tend to change their usernames, and even if that functionality doesn't exist in your app right now, maby it will in a few years. When that day comes, you might have 1000 tables that reference that user-table, and then you'll have to update all 1000 tables within a transaction, and that's just bad.

Comment: isn't "on update cascade" property of foreign key there to take care of such situations? Or am I missing something? I do agree with the 4 bytes/ 4 characters point. But I do not agree with the second argument.

Comment: Sure, you can do that, but it's still bad. That update will probably take more time and create more locks than is acceptable. But if that isn't a problem for the specific application, go ahead. I still wouldn't recommend it though.

Answer (score 4):

int will index faster, may or may not be an issue, hard to say based on what you have provided

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the foreign key:  If your company has control over it, then I recommend using an Int if there is an ID field for it.  However, sometimes an ID field is not on a table because another key makes sense as an alternate unique key.   So, the ID field might be a surrogate key in that case.

Rule of thumb: Your foreign key data type should match your primary key data type.

Here's an exception:  what about foreign keys that don't belong to your company?  What about foreign keys to databases and APIs that you have no control over?  Those IDs should always be strings IMO.

To convince you, I ask these questions:

Are you doing math on it?  Are you incrementing it?  Do you have control over it?  APIs are notorious for change, even data types CAN be changed in someone else's database... so how much will it mess you up when an int ID becomes a hex?