# Foreign key constraints: When to use ON UPDATE and ON DELETE

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys

I'm designing my database schema using MySQL Workbench, which is pretty cool because you can do diagrams and it converts them :P

Anyways, I've decided to use InnoDB because of it's Foreign Key support. One thing I noticed though is that it allows you to set On Update and on Delete options for foreign keys. Can someone explain where "Restrict", "Cascade" and set null could be used in a simple example?

For example, say I have a `user` table which includes a `userID`. And say I have a message table `message` which is a many-to-many which has 2 foreign keys (which reference the same primary key, `userID` in the `user` table). Is setting the On Update and On Delete options any useful in this case? If so, which one do I choose? If this isn't a good example, could you please come up with a good example to illustrate how these could be useful?

Thanks

Answer (score 607, accepted):

Do not hesitate to put constraints on the database. You'll be sure to have a consistent database, and that's one of the good reasons to use a database. Especially if you have several applications requesting it (or just one application but with a direct mode and a batch mode using different sources).

With MySQL you do not have advanced constraints like you would have in postgreSQL but at least the foreign key constraints are quite advanced.

We'll take an example, a company table with a user table containing people from theses company

```
CREATE TABLE COMPANY (
     company_id INT NOT NULL,
     company_name VARCHAR(50),
     PRIMARY KEY (company_id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE USER (
     user_id INT, 
     user_name VARCHAR(50), 
     company_id INT,
     INDEX company_id_idx (company_id),
     FOREIGN KEY (company_id) REFERENCES COMPANY (company_id) ON...
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Let's look at the **ON UPDATE** clause:

- **ON UPDATE RESTRICT** : *the default* : if you try to update a company_id in table COMPANY the engine will reject the operation if one USER at least links on this company.
- **ON UPDATE NO ACTION** : same as RESTRICT.
- **ON UPDATE CASCADE** : *the best one usually* : if you update a company_id in a row of table COMPANY the engine will update it accordingly on all USER rows referencing this COMPANY (but no triggers activated on USER table, warning). The engine will track the changes for you, it's good.
- **ON UPDATE SET NULL** : if you update a company_id in a row of table COMPANY the engine will set related USERs company_id to NULL (should be available in USER company_id field). I cannot see any interesting thing to do with that on an update, but I may be wrong.

And now on the **ON DELETE** side:

- **ON DELETE RESTRICT** : *the default* : if you try to delete a company_id Id in table COMPANY the engine will reject the operation if one USER at least links on this company, can save your life.
- **ON DELETE NO ACTION** : same as RESTRICT
- **ON DELETE CASCADE** : *dangerous* : if you delete a company row in table COMPANY the engine will delete as well the related USERs. This is dangerous but can be used to make automatic cleanups on secondary tables (so it can be something you want, but quite certainly not for a COMPANY<->USER example)
- **ON DELETE SET NULL** : *handful* : if you delete a COMPANY row the related USERs will automatically have the relationship to NULL. If Null is your value for users with no company this can be a good behavior, for example maybe you need to keep the users in your application, as authors of some content, but removing the company is not a problem for you.

usually my default is: **ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE**. with some `ON DELETE CASCADE` for track tables (logs--not all logs--, things like that) and `ON DELETE SET NULL` when the master table is a 'simple attribute' for the table containing the foreign key, like a JOB table for the USER table.

**Edit**

It's been a long time since I wrote that. Now I think I should add one important warning. MySQL has one big documented limitation with cascades. **Cascades are not firing triggers**.  So if you were over confident enough in that engine to use triggers you should avoid cascades constraints.

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/triggers.html

> MySQL triggers activate only for changes made to tables by SQL statements. They do not activate for changes in views, nor by changes to tables made by APIs that do not transmit SQL statements to the MySQL Server

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-program-restrictions.html#stored-routines-trigger-restrictions

**==> See below the last edit, things are moving on this domain**

> Triggers are not activated by foreign key actions.

And I do not think this will get fixed one day. Foreign key constraints are managed by the InnoDb storage and Triggers are managed by the MySQL SQL engine. Both are separated. Innodb is the only storage with constraint management, maybe they'll add triggers directly in the storage engine one day, maybe not.

But I have my own opinion on which element you should choose between the poor trigger implementation and the very useful foreign keys constraints support. And once you'll get used to database consistency you'll love PostgreSQL.

#### 12/2017-Updating this Edit about MySQL:

as stated by @IstiaqueAhmed in the comments, the situation has changed on this subject. So follow the link and check the real up-to-date situation (which may change again in the future).

Comment: `ON DELETE CASCADE : dangerous` -- take with a pinch of salt.

Comment: You will need to be careful of cascading, it can lock up your system if lots of records need to be changed.  Cascde delete should espcially be looked at carefully before using, often you really do want the delete to not occur if there are child records. I wouldn't want a customer delete to wipe out the financial data for the oreders he had previously. Sometimes it is better to make sure cacading is not on and provide a way to amrk records as inactive.

Comment: @regilero Stupid question, but if I have **ON DELETE RESTRICT**, I basically have to delete all entities from lowest to highest? So, if a company has employees, and these employees have several desks, and I wanted to delete the company, I'd have to delete first all the desks, and then the employees, and then the company? 3 steps, whereas if I had **ON DELETE CASCADE**, I'd only have to delete the company, and it'd delete everything

Comment: @Abdul, yes, that's it, very powerful, but also quite dangerous. As removing users and desks may require some archiving or accountability tasks.

Comment: In terms of the business logic, there is one case that might be interesting to `SET NULL` in an `ON UPDATE`: updating a company represents a detachment of the Company>User relation. E.g.: if a company changes its business type, the previous users may no longer be related to that business, therefore `NULL` may be preferable for this index.

Comment: @regilero, it seems content in your first link (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/triggers.html ) to mysql site has changed. It says `This includes changes to base tables that underlie updatable views` instead of  what you pasted i.e. `They do not activate for changes in views`

Comment: @regilero, from your added part in the answer : 'the situation has no changed on this subject' - a misplaced `no`- right ?

Comment: _"I wouldn't want a customer delete to wipe out the financial data for the orders he had previously."_ In a situation like that, you probably still need the customer's data anyway.  Your design should probably be marking the customer as inactive, not deleting their row from the database.  In practice, it's been my professional experience that you actually _very_ rarely want to delete _anything_, preferring to mark inactive by default.  In the cases where permanently deleting _is_ ok, `CASCADE DELETE` is generally also okay, even preferred.  I don't regard it as particularly dangerous.

Comment: There's no need to scare people.  `ON DELETE CASCADE` isn`t inherently dangerous. That's just an opinion. The usefulness of cascade delete is based solely on the specific data model and the business logic surrounding it. The business logic may determine that its use is dangerous. However, cascade delete is useful for example for deleting related join table records when the principal object is deleted.  The join table forms a boundary between records belonging to the the principal record being deleted and compositional objects that exist separately from the principal record.

Comment: @br3nt You are about cascade delete being a valid usage. But it requires at least a pause, and to take some time wandering about side effects (like cascade of triggers). data removal always need some careful thinking (that's why some data models would always prefer an deleted or active boolean than a real deletion).

Comment: @regilero you’ve just described software engineering which needs to happen always.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to consider this in context of the application. In general, you should design an application, not a database (the database simply being part of the application).

Consider how your application should respond to various cases.

The default action is to restrict (i.e. not permit) the operation, which is normally what you want as it prevents stupid programming errors. However, on DELETE CASCADE can also be useful. It really depends on your application and how you intend to delete particular objects.

Personally, I'd use InnoDB because it doesn't trash your data (c.f. MyISAM, which does), rather than because it has FK constraints.

Answer (score 3):

Addition to @MarkR answer - one thing to note would be that many PHP frameworks with ORMs would not recognize or use advanced DB setup (foreign keys, cascading delete, unique constraints), and this may result in unexpected behaviour.

For example if you delete a record using ORM, and your `DELETE CASCADE` will delete records in related tables, ORM's attempt to delete these related records (often automatic) will result in error.

Comment: That would bea reason to not use that particular ORM. Any tool that is that poor at database support is not trustworthy. Foreign keys and cascading deletes or updates are db basics not advanced concepts and no realtional database should ever be designed without foreign key constraints!

Comment: The problem is they throw errors. Is it possible to RESTRICT DELETES but have the engine not generate errors but still maintain the semantics? I would like for my program to still go on while at the same time protect other data from being deleted.