# Deleting from table with foreign keys

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, delete-row

I'm unsure if I have misunderstood something fundamental here, but here goes:

I have a persons table (persons have the typical attributes for persons: names, address, etc.) and a table of elected representatives. The representatives have additional attributes (e.g a deputy representative/substitute representative or someone they them-self are substitutes for). As I have many people and only a few representatives (n<200) I store all attributes common for all people in the persons table, and only the representatives-spesific data in the representatives-table. All "data" in the representatives is relations to the persons-table. This table just reflect the current status of who are cleared for voting (and who are cleared to substitute form him, or he is substituting for).

```
representatives 
(numbers are the pk for persons, and empty cells here are NULL in the db)
_____________________________
|id|has_substitute|is_sub_for|
| 1|           2  |          |
| 2|              |        1 |
| 3|              |          |
| 5|              |          |
```

So comes the day when a representative get bumped off his voting-privileges, and I need to delete him from the representatives, but not in the person-table (he is still a person). The same goes from the people he is a sub for, or people that have been a sub for him. They are FK in my schema, but I do not want to delete them as persons, only the relations to the representative that goes out. Just the row from the representatives table.

```
DELETE FROM representatives WHERE id=1;
```

goes all wrong.
    'Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails'
But I do not intend to delete the persons, just the relations created with the 'representatives'-table.

1. Is there a *DELETE FROM and ignore the relationships (just delete the row)-function* for mysql?
2. Am I modeling this wrong? If so, what would be a better way?

PS: Here's the create table info

```
CREATE TABLE `representatives` (
  `person_id` varchar(33) NOT NULL,
  `permanent_substitute_for_id` varchar(33) DEFAULT NULL,
  `temporarily_substitute_for_id` varchar(33) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`person_id`),
  KEY `representatives_250f5a24` (`permanent_substitute_for_id`),
  KEY `representatives_79c95594` (`temporarily_substitute_for_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `permanent_substitute_for_id_5c64807b` FOREIGN KEY (`permanent_substitute_for_id`) REFERENCES `persons` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `person_id_refs_id_5c64807b` FOREIGN KEY (`person_id`) REFERENCES `persones` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `temporarily_substitute_for_id_5c64807b` FOREIGN KEY (`temporarily_substitute_for_id`) REFERENCES `persones` (`id`) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `persones` (
  `id` varchar(33) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  ..[more stuff]..
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fylkesperspektiv_personer_70fdfe4` (`fylke_id`),
  KEY `fylkesperspektiv_personer_3ab19c51` (`parti_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fylke_id_refs_id_36bce012` FOREIGN KEY (`fylke_id`) REFERENCES `fylkesperspektiv_fylker` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `parti_id_refs_id_c381e045` FOREIGN KEY (`parti_id`) REFERENCES `fylkesperspektiv_partier` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Can you post `CREATE TABLE` statement for all tables involved?

Comment: I'll update the question with this info.

Comment: check that link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720050/foreign-key-constraints-when-to-use-on-update-and-on-delete/6720458#6720458 for details on foreign key parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would define a `rep_id` column for each person and tie that to the `rep` table:

```
ALTER TABLE person
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_person_rep
    FOREIGN KEY (rep_id) REFERENCES rep(rep_id)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

I would also not use the **redundant** `has_substitute` column in the rep table and only use `is_sub_for` and then tie that to the `rep_id` in the same table.

```
ALTER TABLE rep
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_rep_rep
FOREIGN KEY (is_sub_for) REFERENCES rep(rep_id)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

This way, when a rep gets deleted, all of their constutuent persons' rep_id column gets updated to NULL, and their subs in the same table are deleted.  If a rep_id gets changed (not that it should ever happen but just in case), the update is cascaded on its children in both tables.

Answer (score 1):

The error message suggests you have have `persons.representative_id` as foreign key to `representative.id` with `ON DELETE RESTRICT` option (the default). You probably want `ON DELETE SET NULL` instead so you're able to remove a representative and keep the person data.

Alternatively, you can have `representative.person_id` as foreign key towards `person.id`.