# Should I add multiple indexes?

Tags: mysql, indexing, database-indexes

*If I have a unique index on a table that covers 2 fields, should I add another index on each field?*

**Example:**

My table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `my_table` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `usersID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `userTypesID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

I then add a unique index which covers both `usersID` and `userTypesID`:

```
ALTER TABLE  `my_table` ADD UNIQUE  `usersID_userTypesID` (  `usersID` ,  `userTypesID` )
```

***Is it worth me adding 2 more indexes, one on `usersID` and another on `userTypesID`?*** e.g:

```
ALTER TABLE  `my_table` ADD INDEX (  `usersID` )
ALTER TABLE  `my_table` ADD INDEX (  `userTypesID` )
```

***Would adding these extra indexes speed up some queries?*** Such as:

```
SELECT      `usersID`
FROM        `my_table`
WHERE       `userTypesID` = 101
```

Or

```
SELECT      `usersTypesID`
FROM        `my_table`
WHERE       `usersID` = 29
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[In *theory*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) the index on `(usersID, userTypesID)` will also act as an index on `usersID` by itself, because it's the left most column.

You would benefit from an index on `userTypesID` too.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need additional indexes, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764120/does-a-unique-constraint-automatically-create-an-index-on-the-fields).
Also try SHOW INDEXES FROM my_table

Comment: +1, Thanks for the reference question, it confirms Alnitaks answer to be correct, because as stated in the answer mysql can use the leftmost index.

Comment: @Gerve the link in my answer (possibly not very obvious) also talks about using the left-most column.  I said "in theory" in my answer because I've seen circumstances when an index on just the one column worked much better than an index on two.

Comment: I'd suggest trying 
EXPLAIN SELECT .. WHERE usersID=1
EXPLAIN SELECT .. WHERE userTypesID=1 
and vice versa, you will see when index is used and when not. And yes Alnitak's link expains how it works.