# Set as unique a couple of fields in mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, unique-key

I want to set as unique a couple of fields in mysql

ex:
field1 = 10
field2 = 30

I don't want duplicate for this couple of values. How do I set this in phpmyadmin?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE mytable
ADD UNIQUE (field1 );

ALTER IGNORE TABLE mytable
ADD UNIQUE (field2 );
```

Or if you want a combined unique index:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE mytable
ADD UNIQUE (field1,field2 )
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ALTER IGNORE TABLE mytable ADD UNIQUE (field1,field2 )' at line 1 0.000 sec

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD UNIQUE my_unique_index(field1,field2);
```

Explanation:

> As of MySQL 5.7.4, the IGNORE clause for ALTER TABLE is removed and
>   its use produces an error.

Source : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html

> A UNIQUE constraint contains an index definition

Source : [MySQL: UNIQUE constraint without index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19907766/mysql-unique-constraint-without-index)

Comment: Please put some effort in your answer.

Comment: Sorry, I thought this answered perfectly the question, and I didn't know I had to explain why other answer might be wrong and irrelevant. So I will update.