# Is there any sql database not creating an index for a unique constraint?

Tags: sql, indexing, rdbms, unique-constraint

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764120/does-a-unique-constraint-automatically-create-an-index-on-the-fields), but really, it's only about MySQL. **Is there any sql database out there, that does not create an index for a unique constraint?**

Comment: I am not aware of any index that implements unique constraints without a unique index.  That doesn't mean that one doesn't exist, but it would be rather unlikely for performance reasons.

Comment: @GordonLinoff if you write to that column very rarely, or in huge batches, you might want to save the storage space and rather face a penalty on write.

Comment: @usr: Yes, there might be situations, where having the constraint without the index might be desirable. Couldn't one implement this using a check constraint?

Comment: @Elrond . . . I cannot think of a reasonable situation where you would want a unique constraint on a column and not want a unique index -- or at least some structure that is equivalent -- for speeding `insert` and `update` performance.

Comment: @usr `if you write to that column very rarely...` Every `INSERT` is going to write to that column and require a test for unique values. As such, writes to that column will be as frequent as for every other column. `UPDATEs` will be less frequent for the column, of course; but every `INSERT` would have to do a full table scan every time.

Comment: I think everybody agress, that it is a good idea to create an index for a unique constraint in 98% of the cases. There might be edge cases where saving the space is preferred by someone, and I start to wonder whether a check constraint would be able to solve those cases. Note my question is about normal unique constraints.

Comment: What would such a constraint look like? Normally a check constraint checks values within a single row. It cannot compare anything in *this* row to something in *that* row. You could write an `isUnique` function, I suppose, where such a thing is allowed, but that function must perform a complete table scan every time a row is inserted or the unique field is updated. That's an awful lot of work and just gets worse as the table grows. Is the small amount of space saved by not having an index worth it? How much extra space does an index take? I don't know the answer but I can't imagine it's a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one sense, no one can give you a definitive answer.  As we speak, someone could be creating that very thing.  But it's a fair bet that any DBMS you've heard of or are likely to hear of will use indexes to enforce uniqueness, because that's what the science dictates.

DBMSs use indexes for this because searching them is quick.  The index uses some kind of structure that supports a binary search, providing *O(log N)* time complexity.

Consider what the system would have to do without such a structure.

```
for each row to be inserted
    scan all rows in table
    error if found
```

In the *best case* -- when there's no error -- each inserted row would cause a scan of the entire table.  That's *O(nm)* complexity, a/k/a *exponential time*.

Suppose for example you're inserting 10,000 rows into a 10,000-row table.  You're looking at 100,000,000 = 10,000 * 10,000 comparisons!  A binary search, by contrast, requires ~13 comparisons for 10,000 rows, and ~17 for 20,000.  Because we're inserting into the same table we're comparing to, the number of comparisons on average will be 15, so the total number of comparisons is 150,000 = 15 * 10,000, or **0.15%** of the work.

Databases are all about scale, and exponential time even at modest scale is infeasible.

On an ordinary machine I have handy, a simple program to compare two unsorted arrays of 10,000 integers takes 0.1 seconds.  As we might expect, 100,000 integers takes 10 seconds, 100 times longer.  At 1,000,000 integers, we could expect 1000 seconds, or about 15 minutes.  A cool billion would take a million times longer, until sometime in the year 2042.

[Rob Pike](http://users.ece.utexas.edu/~adnan/pike.html) likes to say, *Fancy algorithms are slow when n is small, and n is usually small.*  It's true.  But rule #5 is just as important: *Data dominates.*