# Trying to set Foreign Key as string datatype

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am new at Laravel and I have a primary key field which is string because the project i am working on right now which requires underscore (_). Like this: `0001_0001`. Since the primary key is string i also have to set foreign key as string. So, I want to know is there any way to set string as foreign key. I am using `mysql database` as the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with `$table->string('user_id')->unique();`
it will help you and If you would like the relationship to use a value other than id, you may pass a third argument to the `hasOne` method specifying your custom key:
Like this:

```
return $this->hasOne('App\Phone', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```

Answer (score 0):

The declaration will same for the int or string

```
Schema::table('priorities', function($table) {
       $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
   });
```

But the performance will be differ please check the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813727/is-string-or-int-preferred-for-foreign-keys) for more info.

Comment: yup that is true. but what i want is to set the reference on string i.e. not  on `id` but on `unique_id` which is `string` and `unique` but not primary key

Comment: I think it's not a problem are you getting any error when you use strings?

Comment: yes, i do get error. `1215 error: Cannot add foreign key constraint unique_id`. This error is thrown because unique_id is string in another table

Comment: Are you sure you are using same datatypes in both tables? Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16969060/mysql-error-1215-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint