# Not able to set foreign key in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to reference the 'title' column of questions_solutions_language table to the 'title' column of questions table but i am not able to do so

My questions_solutions_language migration

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('questions_solutions_language', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('language');
            $table->text('solution');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::table('questions_solutions_language', function($table)
        {
            $table->foreign('title')
            ->references('title')->on('questions')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

My Questions migration:

```
  $table->id();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('url');
            $table->string('category');
            $table->string('difficulty');
            $table->string('languages')->nullable(true);
            $table->timestamps();
```

I tried referencing the id column of questions_solutions_language to the id column of questions and it works fine. But as soon as i try to reference the string column i get error. I also tried doing the migrations separately still it doesnt work. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: it is because foreign id columns in laravel are supposed to be unsigned big integer, since id column is unsignedbigint then it works. I'd also suggest use $table->foreignIdFor('table') instead of doing this manually.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is there no way to set strings as foreign key then?

Comment: no that's not how mysql foreign keys are supposed to work you can use ID's for it and work with it.

Comment: As long I know foreign keys are based in primary keys.
Maybe this explanation gives you more details
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813727/is-string-or-int-preferred-for-foreign-keys

Comment: So are you saying i should set my primary key to string column and then try again?

Comment: yes if you make title primary and remove $table->id() in question can work but keep in mind storing same strings on 2 tables is not a good practice and bad for db normalization (3NF) ie "3NF is used to reduce the data duplication." for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723998/what-are-database-normal-forms-and-can-you-give-examples

Comment: Ohk thanks will check soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use string column as foreign key, but your `questions.title` column should have unique index.