# database structure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table A with a composite primary key and I have table B where I need to have Table A's colum(s) as foreign key. Do I need to add both column's of Table A in Table B as foreign key?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [surrogate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63090/surrogate-vs-natural-business-keys) in table A to use as the primary key, and use the composite key columns as a [superkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superkey) (create a unique, non-null index on the columns). Have the foreign key in table B refer to the surrogate column.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you have to add all the columns from table A that defines the primary key to table B.

Comment: +1.  If you didn't add all of the columns then you couldn't uniquely identify the rows from table A.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add both column of table A in table B and can make only One column of table A as foreign Key in table B and also can make both column of table A as foeign key in table B.