# Cannot set foreign key in the table

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I have 2 tables.

```
login (login_id primary key 
Email varchar(254) not null
Password varchar(20) not null)
```

and

```
registration(
id PK
Email
password
name
... etc

)
```

I m trying to set email of login as foreign key and registration(email) as references.
but I m not able to do it
ALTER TABLE login ADD FOREIGN KEY(email) REFERENCES registraion(email);

I m using it for a project so that i cud match the login and registraion email while logging in as user.
can someone plz help

Comment: What do you mean "not able to do `alter table...`"? Does it throw an error? If so, what does it say?

Answer (score 1):

The column definitions in the 2 tables have to match for an FK to be created.

```
registration( id PK, Email VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL, password name
```

The datatype and length of the columns in both table must match.

Comment: both the columns are email

Comment: VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL I mean, name does not matter in the least but the data type and length do

Comment: even they are the same

Comment: well they are not the same in your code so what use is that, If you want good answers to your question include the code you are actually using. WE are not miond readers you know. So post your full table create statements please.

Answer (score 0):

Foreign Key can be created by referencing a **Primary Key** on another table or a **Unique Key** with certain restriction such as column type and size. The type and size of both the columns must match.

For a more detailed discussion on the facts you may reference this SO post [mysql-non-primary-foreign-key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118739/mysql-non-primary-foreign-key) and this MySql reference manual [create-table-foreign-keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)