# database normalization, numerical primary key or string

Tags: sql, database, normalization

I had to argue with my professor about this, but he insist that my solution was anomalous and may cause conflicts. He added that I fail at understanding the concept of database designing.

But then, he is unable to explain to me why his solution is correct whilst mine is wrong.

The question is about database normalization of the following kena database table:

[image: Question]

And MY answer on the left side, and the Professor's answer on the right side:

[image: Answers]

Better View: 
http://tny.cz/48c4a28b

What do you think is my mistake and why do you think he said that my answer is far from correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few issues here.

1. As others have pointed out, subtotal is derived, and so shouldn't be included.
2. Professor fails to capture project leader, which, it would appear, can't be otherwise derived. In the original, it's stored with the employee_name, which actually made my eye tick.
3. As others have said, using a surrogate key in places where a pk based on name could change is expected and normal.
4. Total_charge is another derived field, and shouldn't be included in a 3nf solution.

No, you're not way off. You included a couple derived fields, which is a pretty common mistake in modeling 3nf. Your professor isn't way off either, but if I were interviewing him, I'd dig a little deeper into this.

Answer (score 1):

not much to actually answer here - but here goes... your professor is correct.

1. subtotal is not appropriate for the concept of project - does not belong in that table.
2. employee - same - seems ok - but really the jobclass may change over time and does not belong in either
3. jobclass should have all 3 columns as you show - id, name and charge
4. line item - same so ok.

also, project leader seems to be an additional concept.  should not be part of this answer since it does not seem to appear in the base table you are working on.

Comment: but am I far from correct?

Answer (score 1):

There are two significant differences.

Firstly, you seem to store the sub total along the project. That's duplicating information - you can get the subtotal by summing the charge per project. A key aspect of database design is "don't repeat yourself".

The second is that you've created a meaningless primary key for "jobclass", whereas your professor uses the name of the jobclass as the primary key.

Ideally, you want your primary key to be unique (both solutions meet this). You also want it to be unchanging - and this is where I'd rank your solution as better - what happens when you change the description of job class "sys analyst"?

Comment: why do you think the primary key for jobclass is meaningless?

Comment: It has no inherent business meaning - it's a surrogate key.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you use the jobclass name or a surrogate key, both is ok and correct from a practical standpoint. If you use the name, the name is very hard to change because it is being used as part of FK relations. That's why a surrogate ID like in your answer is typically assigned.

It is also more space efficient (which is a physical concern).

Primary keys should be small and stable so I like the ID-based solution.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a natural key vs surrogate key question? We've had these [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63090/surrogate-vs-natural-business-keys). Or is it about the subtotal you have in the project table? That is indeed a 3NF violation.