# Force a constraint in primary key to have "@" in MS Access

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2010

How do make sure that the primary key has one "@" in the column "email" in MS Access database, so it does not save any data without one "@" and throw exception.

I also have one column that saves domain names and it should have one "."

How do I do this validation too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Add the following "validation rule" to your field

  ```
  Like "*@*"
  ```
- Add a "validation text" with a descriptive error message, e.g.

  ```
  E-mail address must contain at least one @
  ```

---

As a side note: I would strongly advise *against* using an e-mail address as a primary key. The primary key is used to create references between tables and should usually be a value that *won't change*. E-mail addresses, however, do change. You might want to consider using an *AutoNumber field* instead (a so-called "surrogate key" which has [certain advantages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63090/87698)).

Comment: I also have one column that saves domain names and it should have one dot "." How do I do this validation too?

Comment: Please can you look at this problem and let me know what I am missing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17213787/sql-executes-well-in-ms-access-but-not-in-c-sharp-when-validation-rule-is-set