# Products table to handle attributes combo

Tags: mysql, database-design, entity-attribute-value

I want the admin to have an option when adding a product in marketplace such as for example he is adding a shirt.

So he would have option add any number of options and (Combination of options). Each combination can have different price and quantity.

This is like WooCommerce in Wordpress handles variable products.

As of now i have made following tables

**products:**

```
id | sku| brand_id | vendor_id | name | image
```

**attributes:**

```
id | name
```

**products_attributes:**

```
id | attribute_id | product_id | attribute_value
```

By this structure i am able to store multiple attributes for a single product but unable to achieve a combination feature.

Use case : Adding a Shirt having below details

```
color : black , size: M , price : 10$, stock: 10
color : black , size: L , price : 20$, stock: 5
```

Thanks

Comment: i think your question is premature. I think you need to think more about how you want it all to work - whether for instance you intend to price every combo, or just the components - like extra toppings on a pizza - and whether at a fixed price or relative price.

Comment: Acutally i want it go be generalized like if its a simple product than it should have a fixed price. If its a variable product like `clothing` the seller would have option to deep down into pricing as much as possible. My idea is not to hard code the attributes. Every category can have any attribute and its upto seller what he adds. So in the front end i will provide him a text field instead of a dropdown.

Comment: See same question answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21010251/inventory-management-with-stock-options/21113170#21113170)