# Do I need auto increment int value primary key if I have column with unique varchar value?

Tags: database, db2

I've a general question regarding DB design. We have datatable where on of the column has unique varchar value, it's enough to distinguish between different rows. But I think we also should add autoincrement primary key based on int value, and my colleague doesn't agree with me.
My reasons are following:

1. Working with int values is more cheaper than varchars values.
2. Interconnection between tables based on int key is more acceptable.

My colleague thinks that one unique key is enough, who is right? 
Thank you.

Comment: I tend to agree with your colleague - at least if your character data isn't too large. If you add another artificial key you wind up with two unique indexes that need to be maintained for each delete and insert. However there is indeed an overhead for character data (in size and CPU cost) but unless you are storing hundreds of millions rows I doubt you could measure the difference in speed.

Comment: I not need to maintain column with varchar values, I get it from outside and store it's data only to connect to other internal systems. I'm talking about employee's id.

Comment: But thank you for your answer, I will take it in account.

Comment: If that varchar column is unique you need to have a unique index. And every insert/delete **will** update that index regardless whether you "maintain" that varchar value or not. Additional indexes mean additional work for DML statements.

Answer (score 1):

That question is an ongoing debate..

[Surrogate vs. natural/business keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63090/surrogate-vs-natural-business-keys)

https://www.google.com/search?q=natural+keys+vs+surrogate+keys

You mention that "you need to maintain column with varchar values"  I read that to mean you see that natural key changing often.  In which case it isn't a natural key.

On the other hand, you mention it is an employee ID which usually is a natural key.  And given that the data is coming in from outside, you'd be hard pressed to maintain your table unless it is a natural key.

Read up on Joe Celko's and Chris Date's thoughts about keys and make up your own mind.