# Why it is better to create unique key than composite key?

Tags: database, normalization, rdbms

Why it is important to create unique key than composite key ?

In 1st Normalization form we create composite key. But why developers say that it is better to create unique key than composite . It is a relation of functional dependency?

Comment: Umm, a "*composite key*" can also be a "*unique key*".  Unique keys are not necessarily limited to a single column.  Do you perhaps mean a "*uniquely generated single column key*"?  Also known as a "*synthetic key*"?

Comment: composite keys are more difficult to join

Comment: The phrase "unique key" is redundant; every "key" is unique. You seem to mean, a (redundant) surrogate key added to natural keys. Instead of "composite key" you probably mean "natural key(s) (only)". "A [surrogate key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) may also be called a synthetic key, an entity identifier, a system-generated key, a database sequence number, a factless key, a technical key, or an arbitrary unique identifier." Ie non-"natural key" or non-"business key". Please edit your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Surrogate vs. natural/business keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63090/surrogate-vs-natural-business-keys)