# integer on 4 positions on apache derby

Tags: java, derby, sqlexception

I want the ID for the client to be on 4 positions like "0007" on apache derby but the following request doesn't work:

```
create table client(id int (5)  not null AUTO_INCREMENT primary key, fname varchar(20) not null, lname varchar(20) not null,phnum int(10) not null, email varchar(60) not null ) ;
```

it throws this exception:

```
[Exception, Error code 30 000, SQLState 42X01] Erreur de syntaxe : Encountered "(" at line 1, column 28.
```

how can I make it happen ?

Answer (score 0):

1. The Derby `int` has no width. It is soley an [integer](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/ref/rrefsqlj10696.html).
2. You may use [formatting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-), to use the id as a 4 digit wide string.
3. Probably you will use your Derby data later in Java thrua a ORM. It is not [recomended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63090/surrogate-vs-natural-business-keys) to use business data as an object id. Let the id an auto-incrementet value to identify your object. You may add another field (like code) to have the client code stored (char(4) with a unique index to avoid duplicates).

(4. Only preview 10.000 clients, that seems a quiet low limit)

Comment: it's just a simple exemple soo i don't need to add alot but thank you anyway